# SQL Server Graph Database - shortest path using multiple edge types

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases, sql-graph

I have done my research on SQL Server GraphDB, but all the contrived examples I've found so far use only a single edge table. It's always `Person-friend_of->Person`, for example. In my case, I've created a graph of deployed software components in our datacentre, and there are different edges/relationships. Things like `Application-connects_to->SqlDatabase` and `Server-hosts->Application`.

I want to write a query that will show me the shortest path between any two nodes, regardless of the Edges used. I think if I was using Neo4j, I'd write the `MATCH` as something like:

`Server-*->SqlDatabase` Notice the asterisk.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

Since SQL Server 2019 you can do exactly that using derived tables or views. I couldn't find any official documentation of this feature, but i found a small remark in a [video about Bill of Materials](https://learn.microsoft.com/shows/Data-Exposed/Exploding-Bill-of-Materials-using-Graph-Shortest-Path).
The problem is, that it is currently (SQL Server 2019) buggy and doesn't work as expected (or as I would expect it to work).

edit: They have some links in that video, but we need to be concerned only with this [Github example](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/sql-graph/DerivedTablesAndViewsInGraphMatch?WT.mc_id=dataexposed-c9-niner).

edit 2: I have discovered a major bug, that basically disqualifies heterogenous queries from real-world usage.

The point is that you use a `UNION ALL` of multiple *EDGE* (or *NODE*) tables to serve as one *EDGE* (or *NODE*) table in the `MATCH` operator.

- You **should use View** if you use subselect, you are a little limited in what you can do (see below)
- You can use **SUBSELECT**, but you won't be able use columns of the subselect in aggregate functions (it may be possible, but than it is not easy to use and it is definitely not documented)
- You can *not* use **Common Table Expression**

## Example

This example uses *heterogenous* node view and *heterogenous* edge view. It also depicts two major (I would call it a bug, but it may be a feature, this is a question for M$ to answer) **bugs**:

1. If you are looking for a shortest_path between two *heterogenous* nodes, all of them must be *heterogenous*. If you start with a *specific* node and than proceed with *heterogenous* node, the algorithm will for whatever reason be able to traverse the graph only one edge away from the starting node.
2. If you try to use aggregate functions on the *node* or *edge* tables from the path, they currently work correctly only for the *edge* table rows; aggregate functions on *node* rows returns a random (?) garbage.

```sql
/** TOC:
* 1. prepare tables
* 2. prepare data
* 3. prepare heterogenous views
* 4. QUERIES
* 4.a. BUG 1
* 4.b. BUG 2
* 4.c. WORKS
**/

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

/*******************\
| 1. prepare tables |
\*******************/
CREATE TABLE graph.SmallCities   (Name nvarchar(1000), Weight INTEGER, SmallCity_ID INTEGER IDENTITY(666,666) PRIMARY KEY) AS NODE;
CREATE TABLE graph.LargeCities   (Name nvarchar(1000), Weight INTEGER, LargeCity_ID INTEGER IDENTITY(666,666) PRIMARY KEY) AS NODE;
CREATE TABLE graph.Villages      (Name nvarchar(1000), Weight INTEGER, Village_ID   INTEGER IDENTITY(666,666) PRIMARY KEY) AS NODE;
CREATE TABLE graph.Hamlets       (Name nvarchar(1000), Weight INTEGER, Hamlet_ID    INTEGER IDENTITY(666,666) PRIMARY KEY) AS NODE;

CREATE TABLE graph.Hikes     (INDEX UQ UNIQUE nonclustered ($from_id, $to_id)) AS EDGE;
CREATE TABLE graph.Footpaths (INDEX UQ UNIQUE nonclustered ($from_id, $to_id)) AS EDGE;
CREATE TABLE graph.Roads     (INDEX UQ UNIQUE nonclustered ($from_id, $to_id)) AS EDGE;
CREATE TABLE graph.Railways  (INDEX UQ UNIQUE nonclustered ($from_id, $to_id)) AS EDGE;

INSERT INTO graph.SmallCities (Name, Weight) VALUES (N'SmallCityOnRoad', 3);
INSERT INTO graph.LargeCities (Name, Weight) VALUES (N'BigCityOnRailway', 5), (N'BiggishCityOnR&R', 4);
INSERT INTO graph.Villages    (Name, Weight) VALUES (N'VillageInMountains', 2);
INSERT INTO graph.Hamlets     (Name, Weight) VALUES (N'HutInThePass', 1);

/*****************\
| 2. prepare data |
\*****************/
INSERT INTO graph.Railways
  ($from_id, $to_id) 
SELECT
  L1.$node_id, L2.$node_id
FROM
  graph.LargeCities AS L1,
  graph.LargeCities AS L2
WHERE
  L1.Name = N'BigCityOnRailway' 
  AND L2.Name = N'BiggishCityOnR&R';

INSERT INTO graph.Roads
  ($from_id, $to_id) 
SELECT
  L1.$node_id, L2.$node_id
FROM
  graph.LargeCities AS L1,
  graph.SmallCities AS L2
WHERE
  L1.Name = N'BiggishCityOnR&R'
  AND L2.Name = N'SmallCityOnRoad';

INSERT INTO graph.Footpaths
  ($from_id, $to_id) 
SELECT
  L1.$node_id, L2.$node_id
FROM
  graph.SmallCities AS L1,
  graph.Villages AS L2
WHERE
  L1.Name = N'SmallCityOnRoad'
  AND L2.Name = N'VillageInMountains';

INSERT INTO graph.Hikes
  ($from_id, $to_id) 
SELECT
  L1.$node_id, L2.$node_id
FROM
  graph.Villages AS L1,
  graph.Hamlets AS L2
WHERE
  L1.Name = N'VillageInMountains'
  AND L2.Name = N'HutInThePass';

GO

/*******************************\
| 3. prepare heterogenous views |
\*******************************/
CREATE VIEW graph.AllResidentialAreas AS
  SELECT
    LC.$node_id AS node_id,
    LC.Name,
    LC.Weight,
    LC.LargeCity_ID AS Area_ID,
    'Large city' AS AreaType
  FROM
    graph.LargeCities AS LC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    SC.$node_id AS node_id,
    SC.Name,
    SC.Weight,
    SC.SmallCity_ID,
    'Small city' AS AreaType
  FROM
    graph.SmallCities AS SC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    V.$node_id AS node_id,
    V.Name,
    V.Weight,
    V.Village_ID,
    'Village' AS AreaType
  FROM
    graph.Villages AS V
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    H.$node_id AS node_id,
    H.Name,
    H.Weight,
    H.Hamlet_ID,
    'Hamlet' AS AreaType
  FROM
    graph.Hamlets AS H;

GO

CREATE VIEW graph.AllPaths AS
  SELECT
    $edge_id AS edge_id,
    $from_id AS from_id,
    $to_id AS to_id,
    'Railway' AS PathType
  FROM
    graph.RailWays
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    $edge_id,
    $from_id AS from_id,
    $to_id AS to_id,
    'Road' AS PathType
  FROM
    graph.Roads
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    $edge_id,
    $from_id AS from_id,
    $to_id AS to_id,
    'Footpath' AS PathType
  FROM
    graph.Footpaths
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    $edge_id,
    $from_id AS from_id,
    $to_id AS to_id,
    'Hike' AS PathType
  FROM
    graph.Hikes;

GO

/************\
| 4. QUERIES |
\************/

/*************
| 4.a. BUG 1 - combining views and underlaying tables doesn't work
*/
SELECT
  STRT.Name AS FromArea,
  LAST_VALUE(NOD.Name) within GROUP (graph PATH) AS ToArea,
  STRT.NAME + '->' + STRING_AGG(NOD.Name, '->') WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Way
FROM
  graph.LargeCities                  AS STRT, -------this is a problem, view vs edge table
  graph.AllPaths            FOR PATH AS PTH,
  graph.AllResidentialAreas FOR PATH AS NOD
WHERE 1=1
  AND MATCH(
    SHORTEST_PATH(
      STRT(-(PTH)->NOD)+
    )
  )
  AND STRT.NAME = 'BigCityOnRailway';

/**OUTPUT:
--The problem is, that the SHORTEST_PATH doesn't "see" more than one step behind the starting underlaying table
FromArea          ToArea            Way
BigCityOnRailway  BiggishCityOnR&R  BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R
BigCityOnRailway  SmallCityOnRoad   BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R->SmallCityOnRoad
*/

/*****************
| 4.b. BUG 2 - using node rows along the SHORTEST_PATH found
*/
SELECT
  STRT.Name AS FromArea,
  LAST_VALUE(NOD.Name) within GROUP (graph PATH) AS ToArea,
  STRING_AGG(PTH.PathType, '->') WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Path,
  STRT.NAME + '->' + STRING_AGG(NOD.Name, '->') WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Way, --this has problem
  SUM(NOD.Weight) WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Weight, --this has similar problem
  COUNT(PTH.PathType) WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Path_Length
FROM
  graph.AllResidentialAreas          AS STRT,
  graph.AllPaths            FOR PATH AS PTH,
  graph.AllResidentialAreas FOR PATH AS NOD
WHERE 1=1
  AND MATCH(
    SHORTEST_PATH(
      STRT(-(PTH)->NOD)+
    )
  )
  AND STRT.Name = 'BigCityOnRailway'
  AND STRT.AreaType = 'Large city';

/**OUTPUT
--This correctly finds the "transitive closure" (columns FromArea and ToArea)
--This correctly finds the edges that need to be traversed (column Path)
--BUT the nodes along the way are wrong - see the last two rows:
--  first, second and the last nodes are OK,
--  but all the nodes between are just the first node repeated
--  this is also visible in the Weight column, where the correct weights should be (4, 7, 9, 10)
FromArea          ToArea              Path                           Way                                                                                   Weight  Path_Length
BigCityOnRailway  BiggishCityOnR&R    Railway                        BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R                                                    4       1
BigCityOnRailway  SmallCityOnRoad     Railway->Road                  BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R->SmallCityOnRoad                                   7       2
BigCityOnRailway  VillageInMountains  Railway->Road->Footpath        BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R->BigCityOnRailway->VillageInMountains              11      3
BigCityOnRailway  HutInThePass        Railway->Road->Footpath->Hike  BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R->BigCityOnRailway->BigCityOnRailway->HutInThePass  15      4
*/

/***********************************
| 4.c. WORKS, but isn't heterogenous
*/
CREATE TABLE graph.AllAreas (Name nvarchar(1000), Weight INTEGER, Area_ID INTEGER IDENTITY(666,666) PRIMARY KEY, AreaType VARCHAR(1000)) AS NODE;
CREATE TABLE graph.AllWays (PathType VARCHAR(1000), INDEX UQ UNIQUE nonclustered ($from_id, $to_id)) AS EDGE;

INSERT INTO graph.AllAreas
  (Name, Weight, AreaType)
SELECT
  ARA.Name,
  ARA.Weight,
  ARA.AreaType
FROM
  graph.AllResidentialAreas AS ARA WITH(NOLOCK);

INSERT INTO graph.AllWays
  ($from_id, $to_id, PathType)
SELECT
  AA_FROM.$node_id,
  AA_TO.$node_id,
  AP.PathType
FROM
  graph.AllPaths AS AP
  JOIN graph.AllResidentialAreas AS ARA_FROM ON ARA_FROM.node_id = AP.from_id
  JOIN graph.AllResidentialAreas AS ARA_TO   ON ARA_TO.node_id   = AP.to_id
  JOIN graph.AllAreas AS AA_FROM ON AA_FROM.Name = ARA_FROM.Name
  JOIN graph.AllAreas AS AA_TO   ON AA_TO.Name   = ARA_TO.Name;

SELECT
  STRT.Name AS FromArea,
  LAST_VALUE(NOD.Name) within GROUP (graph PATH) AS ToArea,
  STRING_AGG(PTH.PathType, '->') WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Path,
  STRT.NAME + '->' + STRING_AGG(NOD.Name, '->') WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Way, --this has problems too, 
  SUM(NOD.Weight) WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Weight, --this has similar problem
  COUNT(PTH.PathType) WITHIN GROUP (graph PATH) AS Path_Length
FROM
  graph.AllAreas          AS STRT,
  graph.AllWays  FOR PATH AS PTH,
  graph.AllAreas FOR PATH AS NOD
WHERE 1=1
  AND MATCH(
    SHORTEST_PATH(
      STRT(-(PTH)->NOD)+
    )
  )
  AND STRT.Name = 'BigCityOnRailway'
  AND STRT.AreaType = 'Large city';

/**OUTPUT:
FromArea          ToArea              Path                           Way                                                                                    Weight  Path_Length
BigCityOnRailway  BiggishCityOnR&R    Railway                        BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R                                                     4       1
BigCityOnRailway  SmallCityOnRoad     Railway->Road                  BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R->SmallCityOnRoad                                    7       2
BigCityOnRailway  VillageInMountains  Railway->Road->Footpath        BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R->SmallCityOnRoad->VillageInMountains                9       3
BigCityOnRailway  HutInThePass        Railway->Road->Footpath->Hike  BigCityOnRailway->BiggishCityOnR&R->SmallCityOnRoad->VillageInMountains->HutInThePass  10      4
*/

GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
```

Comment: Why did you add OPTION(RECOMPILE) after every insert?

Comment: @Jerry Nixon - sorry it is a habit of mine. I will remove them promptly 
I use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` for ad-hoc queries so their execution plans are not stored. I try to teach that to all my collagues so that our plan cache is not full of unusable plans.